# Validate an enum value in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, validation

I am building a restapi and a parameter in the requestbody is mapped to an enum.

```
public class CarDto{
   
  private Level level;

}
```

where level is:

```
public enum Level {
NEW,OLD
}
```

how can I validate that the user in the request enter exactly one of the enum values?

For example, for not empty field I found `@NotBlank(message = "Name is mandatory")` but I cannot figure out a solution for the mentioned case above.

Comment: Nothing to validate here. The value is already limited to `NEW` or `OLD`. Anything else will fail the deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

Add the [hibernate validator](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator) dependency to your project and annotate the Level field with `@EnumFormat`.

```
@EnumFormat(message = "Invalid level")
private Level level;
```

Answer (score 0):

An enum is a collection of named objects, not text.

So your member field `private Level level;` can never be blank. That member field will only hold one of these three values:

- A reference to the automatically-instantiated object named `Level.NEW`
- A reference to the automatically-instantiated object named `Level.OLD`
- `null` (no reference to anything)